# Same domain upload different app in the cloud foundry (PCF)

Tags: reactjs, cloud-foundry

I want to upload two different react app with same domain in colud foundry (PCF).
One app is running on the xyz.com, and want to run other app on the xyz.com/abc.

I have create manifest file for it.

```
Application:
Name: xyz
Path: build
Route:
Router: xyz.com
```

Other manifest file

```
Application:
Name: yzx
Path: build
Route:
Router: xyz.com/abc
```

It is not working. Index
Html is load properly but css and js are not getting.

Comment: Not exactly sure your problem, but please be aware that the platform isn't going to rewrite any URLs or paths in your HTML. When using path-based routing, you may need to update your application to support the path you've assigned. If your app behind xyz.com/abc expects to be running at xyz.com and generates links relative to `/`, then you'll have problems because your resources are under a subfolder. You'd need to adjust the app so it generates links relative to xyz.com/abc.

Comment: Thank you Deniel for reply! What actually problem is there. I included css and js file. Ther are not loaded proper. When I check css path it is look like that.xyz.com/css/main.css I also added the path name but no luck like xyz.com/abc/css/main.css.

Comment: Can you include some more info? Like a screenshot of DevTools -> Network tab in your browser showing the load failures. At the same time, capture `cf logs` from your app so we can see the requests coming to the app. Also, what buildpack & version are you using?

Comment: Actually index.html is working, but what we include js and css are not loading.

Comment: I am using staticfile_buildpack

Comment: Manifest.yml Application: -name: dev path:build routes: - route:xyz.com -route: xyz.com/test.  Xyz.com is working but other path is giving me 404 not found nginx

Comment: Please help me I am stuck from week on this issue Daniel

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand where you're getting stuck and there's not a lot of information here. What do you mean by "path: build" is working? Is that where your files reside? It's not uncommon to have a "dist" or "build" directory where the packaged, minified output resides. If that's the case, you definitely want to set `path` to that location. Path is the root of what get's pushed up as your application.

Comment: I have two application. One of the build in xyz.com and second I want to build on xyz.com/test. When I pushed both application xyz.com is working fine but xyz.com/test is not working.In the xyz.com/test index.html is loaded find but css and js taking root path.